# What are the elements of order $q-1$ modulo $q^2$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Consider the multiplicative group modulo $q^2$ where $q$ is prime. It has $q(q-1)$ many elements.

The elements of order $q$ are exactly $1+kq$ for some $k$ since:
$$(1+kq)^q = 1+ k*q^2 + O(q^3) = 1$$
up to modulo $q^2$.

Presumably the elements of order $q-1$ can also be neatly characterized, but it's escaping me right now. What is the characterization?

Comment: Since there is no easily stated characterization of the elements of order $q-1$ in the multiplicative group $U(q)$ modulo $q$ for $q$ prime, it is not clear what sort of answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you have to exclude $1=1+0\cdot q$ for elements of order $q$.

According to the existence of [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Definition), for any $q$ prime, $(\mathbb Z/q^2\mathbb Z)^{\times}$ is always cyclic, and therefore it has a unique subgroup $U$ of order $q-1$, so the number of elements of order $q-1$ is exactly $\phi(q-1)$.

If $x=a+bq$ (where $a,b\in \{0, 1, \cdots, q-1\}$ and $a\not=0$) is in $U$, i.e. $x^{q-1}=1$, $x^q=x$. We have
$$(a+bq)^q\equiv a+bq \mod q^2$$

With binomial theorem, $(a+bq)^q=\sum_{i=0}^q {q\choose i} a^{q-i}(bq)^i\equiv a^q\mod q^2$

Therefore we have $a^q\equiv a+bq \mod q^2$, then $b\equiv \frac{a^q-a}{q}\mod q$. So $b$ is completely determined by $a$. That is, the unique subgroup of order $q-1$ in $(\mathbb Z/q^2\mathbb Z)^{\times}$ is exactly $$\{a^q\mod q^2 | a= 1, 2, \cdots, q-1 \}$$ Indeed, we have the a  group isomorphism:

$$(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^{\times}\rightarrow U\subset(\mathbb Z/q^2\mathbb Z)^{\times}$$

$$a+q\mathbb Z\mapsto a^q + q^2\mathbb Z$$ $$ a + q\mathbb Z \style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1);}{\mapsto} a+q^2\mathbb Z$$

Or more explicitly the last row is equivalent to $a+bq+q^2\mathbb Z\mapsto a+q\mathbb Z$.

So $a$ has order $q-1 (\text{ mod } q^2)$ iff it has order $q-1 (\text{ mod } q)$, i.e. $a$ is a primitive root $\text{ mod } q$. There doesn't seem to be a way to go any further as there is no closed formula for finding primitive root.

Comment: OP might be satisfied with "$a^q$ where $a$ is a primitive root mod $q$". (Incidentally why is $q$ a prime today?)

Comment: Surely. Well, I guess most of what's written still hold for $q=p^n$, except $2^n$ for $n\ge 3$ has no primitive root. (Don't count on me though).