# Euler Criterion for $q^2$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $q$ be prime.
Let $a$ be an integer from $0$ to $q-1$. Note that this isn't an equivalence class, I'm just talking about the integers up to $q-1$.

I'm looking for a nice expression for the value of $(a^q-a) / q$ modulo $q$. Equivalently, I'm trying to find $a^q$ modulo $q^2$. Euler's criterion gives us the residue modulo $q$ so something similar modulo $q^2$ would be nice.

I know you can construct various residues $a+kq$ using Hensel's lemma, but I'm not sure which residue corresponds to $k=0$.

Alternatively, I was trying something with "differentiating" the expression $(x^q-x)/q$ and using L'Hopital but I wasn't able to get anything clean.

So, how else can you write:

$$\frac{a^q-a}{q}$$

modulo $q$.

Specifically, I'm trying to solve $(a^q-a)/q = c$ for $a$ and similar polynomial systems. My full question is on overflow here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456399/trying-to-solve-for-the-remainder-of-aq-modulo-q

I recently asked this question and the above question is tied to the solution:
[What are the elements of order $q-1$ modulo $q^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786038/what-are-the-elements-of-order-q-1-modulo-q2?noredirect=1#comment10174298_4786038)

Comment: 1. Euler's criterion states $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv (\frac{a}{p})\mod p$ for every odd prime $p$ and $p\nmid a$. 2. Fermat's little theorem states $a^p\equiv a\mod p$ for every prime $p$ and every non-negative integer $a$ 3. modulo $q^2$ , we can only say that if $\gcd(a,q)=1$ , we have $a^{(q-1)q}\equiv 1\mod q^2$ (Euler's theorem) , hence the order must be a divisors of $(q-1)q$.

Comment: If it is a divisor of $q-1$ , we have $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod q^2$ and $q$ is a Wieferich-prime with respect to base $a$.

Comment: Due to Fermat's little, $q\mid(a^q-a)$ so $(a^q-a)/q$ is indeed an integer. Other than this, I can't imagine what else to say. What's not nice about $(a^q-a)/q$ mod $q$?

Comment: @Justauser edited the question. Try to solve the system mod $q$